# SPSS syntax of a quadratic term with interaction

Tags: regression, spss, interaction, quadratic

How looks the syntax of a regression with a quadratic term and interaction in SPSS? In R the code would be:

```
fit <- lm(c ~ a*b + a*I(b^2), dat)
```

or

```
fit <- lm(c ~ a*(b+I(b^2), dat)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `REGRESSION` you need to actually make the variables in the SPSS data file before submitting the command. So if your variables were named the same:

```
COMPUTE ab = a*b. /*Interaction*/.
COMPUTE bsq = b**2. /*squared term*/.
COMPUTE absq = a*bsq. /*Interaction with squared term*/.
```

Then these can be placed on the right hand side of your regression equation.

```
REGRESSION VARIABLES=a,b,bsq,absq,c
 /DEPENDENT=c
 /METHOD=ENTER a,b,bsq,absq.
```

---

I thought you could only do factor variables for the interactions - but I was wrong, you can do continuous variables as well (sorry!). Here is an example using `MIXED` (still you need to make the seperate variables if using `REGRESSION`).

```
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP Case = 1 TO 200000.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.

COMPUTE a = RV.BERNOULLI(0.5).
COMPUTE b = RV.NORMAL(0,1).
COMPUTE ab = a*b /*Interaction*/.
COMPUTE bsq = b**2 /*squared term*/.
COMPUTE absq = a*bsq /*Interaction with squared term*/.
COMPUTE c = 0.5 + 0.2*a + 0.1*b -0.05*ab + .03*bsq -.001*absq + RV.NORMAL(0,1).

VARIABLE LEVEL a (NOMINAL).
RECODE a (0 = 2)(ELSE = COPY).
MIXED c BY a WITH b bsq
  /FIXED = a b b*b a*b
  /PRINT SOLUTION.
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Is it possible that you missed ab in ENTER? Could you give me advice how the syntax is for mixed models (SPSS: MIXED)? Does it looks like: `/MIXED c by a with b bsq absq /FIXED a b bsq ab absq`? Is there also an alternative like: `/MIXED c by a with b bsq \FIXED c by a with b bsq a*bsq`? Or even: `/MIXED a b /FIXED a b b*b a*b a*b*b`?

Comment: Yes @giordano I forgot to include `ab` in the `REGRESSION` command. Yes in `MIXED` (and in other `GENLIN` commands) you can specify the interactions of *factor* variables, but not continuous ones. So given your example, `b*b` would definitely not be valid syntax. (Only variables that follow `BY` can you estimate the interactions like that.)

Comment: Thanks again. I corrected your answer, I hope this is OK. So, the first two syntax are correct and the third wrong? That is, a*b (categorical*numerical) are possible but not numerical*numerical (my intention was to square b)? Also ... b**2 a*b**2 is wrong? Sorry for these questions but it is really difficult to find a grammar of SPSS-coding language in the net.

Comment: @giordano - sorry I was wrong, apparently to can specify continous interactions when using MIXED (I presume you can for GENLIN as well, although I haven't checked for sure). See added example.

Comment: @Andi. Thanks for your simulation. Still I'm confused. In the second last line of the new syntax: `/FIXED = a b b*b a*b`. b*b is identically to bsq? And is there not a missing a*bsq (or a*b*b or a*b**2)? I interprete b*b as b**2.

Comment: @giordano, yes your interpretation is correct, and it appears I ommitted `a*b*b`. I don't have access to a version of SPSS that has MIXED at the moment so I can not test whether `a*b*b` is valid syntax, but I have provided enough here for you to test it out yourself and see the output.